# (Kafka) Spout on storm returning a list of things, can't spread this list to bolts

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I'm new to Storm so please bear with me.

I have a service that sends to kafka a message every time we have a call with the *list of results*.

There is a KafkaSpout that reads every message, and this message contains the beforementioned list.

It's just a JSon and I can unwrap it. Now, here's the problem:

I do this convertion operation in the Scheme with jackson but this scheme can return basically a `Values` object which is NOT a list of object but basically a list of Field-Value pairs.

Another thing could be to get in a Bolt this Values (it's just an extended ArrayList) object and unwrap it in single elements and send each one of them to the next Bolt. Is this a solution? Can I emit multiple objects from a single call to a Bolt?

Is there a smarter solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can emit multiple tuples from a single Bolt. Looking through the execute method in an example bolt located [here](https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html#what-is-storm-39-s-reliability-api)

```
public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
  String sentence = tuple.getString(0);
  for(String word: sentence.split(" ")) {
    _collector.emit(tuple, new Values(word));  //emits multiple tuples
  }
  _collector.ack(tuple);
}
```

As you can see the for loop can emit multiple tuples at the same time. Doing this creates a much bigger message tree. This can cause problems depending on your reliability guarantees and the size of your data.

In my experience it's hard/impossible to manipulate the data inside a KafkaSpout. So a couple notes about your setup.

- The first thing I would try to do is change what the service is sending to Kafka. Can you send it in individual items instead of one big item. If you're unable to change that.
- Setup multiple Bolts like you mentioned, `Spout => UnwrapBolt => ProcessBolt`, where the `UnwrapBolt` takes your one data source and emits them as individual tuples, then the `ProcessBolt` takes each individual tuple and processes them however you desire.

Comment: Thank you morganw09dev. I actually used the first approach, I reduced the messaging with just an item per message. A question: what happens if I emit-ack every tuple instead of acking at the end?

Comment: I don't know if that's possible/advisable??? My interpretation has always been that acking a tuple is usually used to say you're done processing this tuple for a particular Bolt. So it wouldn't make much sense to ack a tuple when you're still doing stuff with it in the same Bolt. I don't know how official that viewpoint is though.

Comment: oh ok. I'll try, I'll let you know what happens :)

Comment: Looking forward to what happens.

Comment: How is "emit-ack every tuple" different from "acking at the end" in terms of results? In the end, the execute method is always processing one Tuple (received) at time, so if you send the ack, you are acknowledging that the processing is finished... If you mean that you want to call the .ack method in the for loop, well, I think that it's just wrong, because if the collector fails to emit your new tuples to the next bolt, then you'll never get the same tuple again, because it has already been acked. Additionally, in the case you are using a transactional topology, you don't need to ACK.